# Image is not rendering on html page

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-bind-html, ngsanitize

I have issue in rendering image on UI, I have used `ng-bind-html`. I am getting the text as it is but image is not shwoing.

In angular-

```
$scope.conversation.message= $sce.trustAsHtml(response);
```

In HTML -

```
<div ng-bind-html="conversation.message" class="coversation-div"></div>
```

what I am getting is only text but the response is

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB4B4.jpg)

Please tell me how to show image also with text.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post the HTML code where you are trying to display the image

Comment: Why aren't you using "ng-src" attribute?

Comment: <div ng-bind-html="conversation.message" class="coversation-div"></div>

Comment: Most time its showing the image but but sometimes image is missing. No matter how many times I try, its not coming.

Comment: @Piyu What is the value of response ?

Comment: @AlonEitan - Sorry It was a bmp image thats why image was plane. Now I uploaded jpg image.